# Undo (ctrl +z) not working in richtextbox with formated text. WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a richTextBox which will change the line(paragraph) color based on the text. Here is my sample code.

```
    private void RTB_Main_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Paragraph para = RTB_Main.CaretPosition.Paragraph;
        TextRange TR = new TextRange(para.ContentStart, para.ContentEnd);
        para.Foreground = TR.Text == "STATUS : PASS" ? Brushes.Green : TR.Text == "STATUS : FAIL" ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;
    }
```

Everything works fine until I try to do an Undo (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>) operation.

Problem scenario:

Type **STATUS : PASS** in the richTextBox. Text color will change to Green (all good).

Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove last **S** (STATUS : PAS). Text color change to black (works fine).

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to get back the **S**. Nothing is happening here.

Why Undo is not working here? Is there a better way to format the text so that the Undo Redo operation will work fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using the SelectionChanged event rather than a TextChanged event?  I have a similar application, using the TextChangedEvent that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> behaves correctly with.  Note that changing the formatting counts as a TextChanged event with a RichTextBox, so you'll have to unhook the event before doing the styling then rehook.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should turned ShortCutsEnabled property ON

```
RTB_Main.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(RTB_Main_KeyDown);

void RTB_Main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Z && e.Control) {
         //Undo users last update somehow
     }
}
```